# save imageview to image in specific folder

Tags: android, file, imageview

I want to save the imageview to image in specific folder , i try this code but it does not work

```
public void saveImage(View v){  
        View content = findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            //File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/image.jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

and this code for calling the function

```
saveImage(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to save file from resources in sd card or?

Comment: @Android-Developer  Yes , i have an app with a gallery of images and i want that the user can save it into his own gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an image file from your app's resources you can proceed like this :

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
InputStream in = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
// Used the File-constructor
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "myNewImage.png"));

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
try {
    // A little more explicit
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
         out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
} finally {
    // Ensure the Streams are closed:
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

and this should do the trick.

Comment: ok , this for save image from "R.drawable.my_image" but how i can save from "R.id.imageView"

Comment: Why you need to save an id of the imageView in sd card?

Comment: because i have option in my app to take image from camera , then the user can edit the color and many other option , all this operation is doing in imageview .

Comment: Instead of saving the id of imageView you should save the bitmap / stream which is returned from camera and which you are using to add effects.